# Form Titles with javascript

Tags: jquery, css

Im using this script for form titles:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-news').each( function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue'));
        $(this).css({'color':'#686868' ,  'font-size':'11px', 'font-weight':'bold'});
    });
    $('.add-news').focus(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue') ){
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css({'color':'#686868' , 'font-size':'11px' ,'font-weight':'bold'});
        }
    });
    $('.add-news').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '' ){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue'));
            $(this).css({'color':'#686868' ,  'font-size':'11px', 'font-weight':'bold'});
        }
    });

});
```

[The example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/BLrBd/)

This code working perfect for inputs, but in textarea, the above css doesnot work. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After removing the obvious errors ('defaultue' instead of 'defaultValue', and missing commas in the objects of the `css` method) it works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/TY2sf/

Comment: It is bold. At 11px (which is far to small anyway) the font you have may not look much different when bold.

Comment: I can see bold font in inputs. Its normal in textarea. and using:
<textarea class="int add-news" defaultValue="Spot" cols="10" >Spot</textarea>

Comment: In the example I posted it is most certainty bold. Which becomes obvious with a larger font size or using a csz

Comment: Sorry, but it's bold. Have you tried a larger font or checked with a DOM/CSS inspector? Or I guess we need more information. What browser? What font is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is using .html() instead of .val() on TextArea elements.

Comment: i think your right, as text for inputs are stored within `value=""` you use `val()` but as textareas are stored as innerhtml you use `html()` :)

Comment: You have three calls changing css, which one doesn't work? Try using firefox error console to see if there is any error.

Comment: Indeed. `html()` should definitely not be used. It should to map to `defaultValue`, but doesn't in IE due to a bug.